# multiple prints on epson

Tags: printing, epson

I use ubuntu 22.04 and an Epson printer (WF7720).
Unfortunately, Epson doesn't offer any specific drivers, but most of the commands work.
However, since I updated from 20.04 to ubuntu 22.04, I can only print 1 copy at a time - no matter what I set.
Under 20.04 this was at least possible if you created a separate print job for each copy. But now even setting the hook in this checkbox will only create one print file for one copy.
Has anyone an idea how to get the printer print many copies of one sheet?

Comment: Epson does provide drivers for this printer. https://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX Enter `WF-7720`

Comment: Thanks - this not very specific driver is already installed. But they provide a suitable scan driver now, too. unfortunately this scan utility cannot find the scanner if connected via network, only via USB. How can I make find the scan utility a network scanner? -
Just today I managed a multiple print - but can't do it again. Somehow it had to do with the "sort" option - but now whatever I try, only one copy is printed.